# Methods to export Sybase table data using RapidSQL

Tags: sybase, dump, rapidsql

I am trying to export Sybase DB tables using RapidSQL. I am accessing the DB tables as a client as the DB resides on a remote server.

I need to dump the table contents separated by commas onto my local machine.

What are some methods this can be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Sybase bcp utility.  It allows you to export data from the database, table by table.  By default I believe it creates a TAB delineated file, but you can change the field delimiter with the -t option and the row delimiter with the -r option.

More information can be found in the [Sybase documentation here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1502/html/utility/X51453.htm)